# viewPager автолистание

Tags: java, android

Есть ViewPager - хочется реализовать возможность включением пользователем автоматического пролистывания, в баре добавил кнопку по нажатию на которую должно запускать и потом при повторном нажатии останавливать автолистание, есть код который выполняет первую часть, а вот с остановкой никак не выходит. Просьба помочь!

```
    case R.id.menu_auto_slide:
            if (auto_slide) {
                auto_slide = false;
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stop_white_24dp));
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                Thread myThread = new Thread( // создаём новый поток
                        new Runnable() { // описываем объект Runnable в конструкторе
                            public void run() {
                                for (int i = pageCurrent; i < pagerAdapter.getCount() - 1; i++) {
                                    final int value = i;
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            pager.setCurrentItem(value, true);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                myThread.start();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "start " + myThread);

                if (myThread != null) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "myThread != null");
                    myThread.interrupt();
                }

            } else {
                auto_slide = true;
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp));

            }
            return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам тут совершенно не нужен отдельный поток. Просто создаете Runnable в поле:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private int pageCurrent;
private Runnable autoScroll = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pageCurrent++;
            pager.setCurrentItem(pageCurrent, true);
            if (pageCurrent < pagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
            }
        }
    };
```

Затем когда надо запустить выполняете `handler.post(autoScroll)` (предварительно поменяв в pageCurrent стартовую страницу если надо), а останавливаете с помощью `handler.removeCallbacks(autoScroll)`